# Fetch JSON, parse it into an array, and print it in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm trying to fetch json data from an API, parse it into an array of struct, and print the array. But when I try to print it out, only a blank array is returned. I am trying to understand how to write code for asynchronous operations and am not sure where to go from here. Could someone please point me in the right direction? 
I'm trying this out on Playgrounds using Xcode 9, Swift 4.

```html
import Foundation

struct Item: Decodable {
    var userId: Int?
    var id: Int?
    var title: String?
    var body: String?
}

var items = [Item?]()

let completionHandler = { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error occured: \(error.debugDescription)")
        }
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            items = try decoder.decode([Item].self, from: data!)
            print(items)
        } catch {
            print("Error: Unable to fetch data")
        }
    }

func getJson() {
    let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    task.resume()
    print(items)
}

getJson()
```

Comment: Does the `print(items)` inside the `completionHandler` print anything?

Comment: If it doesn't that means your `Item` is not set up properly for your JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to run asynchronous stuff in a Playground you have to add

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

---

Three notes:

1. The `print` line after `resume` is pointless. It will always print an empty array. The `print` line in the completion handler shows the real result
2. Declare `items` as

   ```
   var items = [Item]()
   ```

   `JSONDecoder()` returns something non-optional or throws an error
3. This particular API sends always all fields so you can even declare all struct members as non-optional

   ```
   struct Item: Decodable {
       var userId: Int
       var id: Int
       var title: String
       var body: String
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks @vadian. This works.I was going to work with the 'items' array inside getJson() next. But I realise that's not possible. And, since the dataTask's completion handler returns nothing, I can't work with it there either. If it's not too much to ask along with this question, could you also please tell me where and how to go about doing this?

Comment: Thanks for the three notes as well, @vadian. They helped me understand the concepts better.

Comment: Just do the things you want to do – for example populating a data source array and reloading the table – in the completion handler instead of the print line.